# Why does a different page appear when I try to edit my wordpress site's home page?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

When I click 'edit page' on my website's home page, it takes me to a different, older theme-ed version of the home page, which I no longer want to use. And for some weird reason, the link to both the different pages is same as well.

Answer (score 0):

may be cached plugins is used? what have you set as your homepage, posts or page?